# What is required to build project with ISourceGenerator?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I use ISourceGenerator to generate some source.

On my pc all work well. But on build machine output dll doesn't contain generated sources.

Should i install anything else besides net 6 sdk on build machine?

Comment: Source generators must target netstandard2.0.

Comment: Seems like this one is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49249)

Comment: Use https://aka.ms/msbuildlog to collect a log and see what failed.

Comment: @PauloMorgado didn't find anything interesting in log (/bs). 
But this solved the problem.

`
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset" Version="4.3.1" PrivateAssets="all">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
`